how do i create custom ubuntu iso from scratch?
so i have log aggregator repo in my GitHub. includes all the required files for it and a script which sets up log aggregator on localhost. Now i want to create an ubuntu iso which has this readymade setup of log aggregator. just install the iso and you will have your aggregator setup on localhost on desired port. Now the problem is i don't have any idea how to create iso out of it. i am very new at this. consider i have zero knowledge about this and if anyone can provide a step by step guide with all the proper commands it would be very helpful.

This question is similar to: How do I build a custom Ubuntu ISO that can be booted from USB and used without modification?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
